# Are development questions not welcome?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm not sure if development questions are not welcome on Drupal Answers.

I cannot find any suitable tags related to development. The best matching tag is [developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing), but that one will be removed. So which tags should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal Answers isn't an appropriate place to ask about general software development, but it is definitely the place to ask about Drupal development.

I imagine that the [developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing) tag is to be removed because it's too generalised; no-one could reasonably ascertain the category of a question given just that tag name.

Most importantly, the tags you use should be relevant to the question you're asking.

For example, if you are experiencing problems while developing a custom form, an appropriate tag would be [form-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-api). If you're trying to install a custom field through code, and it's not working, [field-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-api) would be appropriate. And so on.

If you're still unsure, have a look through the questions currently on the front page of the main site. A lot of them are questions about development, and by looking at what *they* have been tagged with, you should be able to get a good feel for your own questions.

Answer (score 1):

As per the FAQ, the following questions are on-topic, on *Drupal Answers*:

- Drupal theory questions
- Server administration/deployment
- Support questions for specific modules that are not about bugs workarounds
- **Drupal development/theming how-tos**
- Site troubleshooting
- Site-building how-tos
- Community involvement

The question needs to be about Drupal; any other question is off-topic.

[developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing) is a tag that is too generic, and it doesn't communicate anything to who answers the question. The fact you are developing a module, or you are asking the code you should write in a text area that asks you to enter PHP code, influences minimally the answers, and it doesn't deserve a tag.